# Dynamically populated table disappearing when triggering update

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

Using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) for the first time. I have a table that is updated dynamically via ajax. When I say updated I do not mean appending removing rows, I simply change a status column in the table.

The sort doesn't seem to work correctly after this. I suspect I need to trigger an update to get the cache to update and for tablesorter to regcognise the change. However when I call this all elements in the table are deleted, header, rows everything. All that is left is the table tag itself.

```
function UpdateTableSort() {
        jQuery("#data-table").trigger("update");
        var sorting = [[0, 0], [1, 0]];
        jQuery("#data-table").trigger("sorton", [sorting]); 
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Ian